# JPQL query with having oracle db

Tags: oracle, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I am using jpql jpa eclipselink Following query wont work :

```
SELECT c FROM TableA c WHERE c.forumId = :forumId AND c.isDefault = true HAVING MAX (c.validFrom)
```

The error im getting "The expression is not a valid conditional expression"

Comment: And since the HAVING clause has to be a boolean / conditional expression then it is totally correct. Why not fix your query to make the HAVING a boolean ... http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/query.html#jpql_grouping

Comment: but i want o get max validFrom how can i make expression ot of this ?

Comment: ok there is no need for max, jus order by valdFom DESC limit 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause [only works](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#HAVING_Clause) with a `GROUP BY` expression.

> The HAVING clause allows for the results of a GROUP BY to be filtered.

Your question is:

> i want o get max validFrom how can i make expression ot of this

But you can make a query without `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to do what you want:

```
select c from TableA c WHERE c.validFrom = (
    SELECT MAX(c2.validFrom) 
    FROM TableA c2  
    WHERE c2.Id = c.Id AND c.forumId = :forumId AND c.isDefault = true
)
```

If you would like to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, you can do:

```
SELECT c FROM TableA c WHERE c.validFROM = (
    SELECT MAX(validFROM) 
        FROM TableA 
        WHERE forumId = :forumId AND isDefault = true
        GROUP BY validFROM
        HAVING validFROM=c.validFROM
)
```